# how to split records returned from a query into sets of 1000 via jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I have a source and a target database and I need to check the count in both, is it same or not.

I fetch a column from source database via below queries:

```
DMS_Arr[0] = "select count(distinct eai_src_pk) from document_id_creation where eai_entry_date > (trunc(sysdate-1) + 00/24) and eai_entry_date < (trunc(sysdate) + 00/24)";
DMS_Arr[1] = "select distinct eai_src_pk from document_id_creation where eai_entry_date > (trunc(sysdate-1) + 00/24) and eai_entry_date < (trunc(sysdate) + 00/24)";
```

Now I store the output of DMS_Arr[1] into a variable "targetPk" separated by commas and use it in my JDBC query to check the count at target side via the below query.

```
ERP_Arr[0] ="select count(distinct eai_src_pk) from xxindus.XXINDUS_ERP_OBRM_PYMT_CNDN_T where eai_src_pk in (" + targetPk + ")" + " and eai_entry_date > (trunc(sysdate-1) + 00/24)";
```

However, the problem is that the records in variable targetPk could be 1000, 10000 or 150000 and database is able to handle only 1000 at a time. How can I make my code handle this and automatically split them into sets of 1000 so that JDBC query does not throw any error. Then I need to store all these values returned into a string variable separated by commas and check the count.

Comment: Do you have a `database link` between the databases? This will save you the coding, just by using .. `where eai_src_pk in (select ... from document_id_creation@remote_db..)`

Comment: No there is no link between the two databases.

Comment: I'd open two queries reading the distinct keys in the same order and fetch from them in a sort of `merge` to see in a particular key is in both sources or in only one of them. You can split a long `IN` list using `OR` but this doesn't happen automatically, you must code it;)